# parameter constructor for class.forName in j2me

Tags: java, java-me

How to  create a parameter constructor for class.forName in j2me

Sample Code:

```
Class A
{

  A()    
  {    
  }

  A(int a)    
  {    
  }
}

//Here is code to call a constructor 

 Object o = Class.forName("org.java.DataMembers.A").newInstance();
```

How to call a parameter constructor in j2me..plz help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty sure the answer is that you can't.  If it's a class you are in charge of, you'll need to create a parameterless constructor...  if not, you'll need to find another way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
Class myClass = Class.forName("org.java.DataMembers.A");
Constructor intConstructor= myClass.getConstructor( Integer.TYPE)
Object o = intConstructor.newInstance( 4);
```

Comment: getConstructor not available in j2me.